# Is it possible to implement own AtomicInteger on Java? (jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe)

Tags: java, atomic, compare-and-swap

Is it possible to implement my own [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) in Java?

What I see under the hood of methods:

```
public final int addAndGet(int delta) {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + delta;         // Only difference
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}

public final int incrementAndGet() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;             // Only difference
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}
```

So anyway need to use compareAndSet. Which is:

```
public final boolean compareAndSet(int expectedValue, int newValue) {
        return U.compareAndSetInt(this, VALUE, expectedValue, newValue);
    }
```

where
`private static final jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe U = jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.getUnsafe()`;

So all atomics use Unsafe ( which I don't know well and highly doubt if one need it at job) which I guess use low-level/cpu instructions

```
Compare and Swap
```

My question is: is it possible to write atomics on java, or anyway need to call `Unsafe` and end up with it?

Comment: No matter what you do, it will eventually have to end up somewhere deep down calling native instructions. That said, there are high level mechanisms in Java available that you can use. For example `synchronized` or locks, mutexes, ...
So you could build your own `AtomicInteger` on top of that. But ultimately those classes or language mechanisms will also end up calling native instructions.

Comment: You don't explicitly have to use `Unsafe`, but maybe `VarHandle`s

Comment: Since you can basically perform any C code via JNI, you can surely write one. But why?